# Recently updated R / RStudio, rJava could not be loaded.

Tags: java, r, rjava

I recently updated R to 3.4 and RStudio to its RStudio v1.0.143 Preview so that it's compatible with the image updates & plots for R, but now I'm having an issue with rJava when trying to load it or packages that require it. It's as follows:

```
Loading required package: rJava
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
 call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so': dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: @rpath/libjvm.dylib
Referenced from: 
 /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
  Reason: image not found
Error: package ‘rJava’ could not be loaded
```

I am presently running MacOSX 10.12.4 Sierra

Any help on how to fix this is great appreciated.

Comment: You may need to reinstall it from source, see the R 3.4.0 NEWS file.

Comment: I've reinstalled Java, what else would I reinstall from source?

Comment: The _rJava_ package may need reinstallation as R 3.4.0 changed how `.C()` and `.Fortran()` calls are resolved. That is in the NEWS file I pointed you to.

Comment: install from outside of rstudio

Comment: Uninstalled it, installed it using the local (IA) R Cran in base R (not RStudio), still getting precisely the same error.

Answer (score 2):

As already noted by @mko, the mix of macOS/R/rJava is mess, albeit a very useful one. I've been wrangling with this issue over several releases of each, and no matter how much care you take it seems it bites again periodically. That said, there are various things to bear in mind:

- You'll require a JDK installation, not just a JRE installation.
- If not using the deprecated Apple version of Java 1.6, R's javareconf script doesn't handle the location of `libjvm.dylib` correctly.
- It's best to use a recent JDK version to benefit from the latest security enhancements.
- R's `javareconf` script fails to *reconfigure* R correctly after upgrading to a new Java version; it requires a reinstallation of R to do it properly.

So, bearing these in mind:

- Install/update JDK.
- It's a good idea to set `JAVA_HOME` correctly for whichever JDK installation you plan to use (generally in *~/.bashrc* or *~/.bash_profile*).
- Install XQuartz if not yet installed (as @mko mentions).
- (Re)install R (to allow correct R configuration against new Java installation.
- Run `javareconf` script with custom parameters to let it configure for the modern JDK.
- Link Java runtime to R's library folder to it can find it.

The custom call to javareconf is just a few lines at the terminal:
Firstly, make sure JAVA_HOME is set as required:

```
# Make sure JAVA_HOME is set as required.
export JAVA_HOME=${JAVA_HOME:-$(/usr/libexec/java_home)}
# Obtain location of Java runtime library.
export LIBJVM=$(find "${JAVA_HOME}" -name 'libjvm.dylib')
# Reconfigure R using custom call to javareconf script.
R CMD javareconf JAVA_LIBS="${LIBJVM}" JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${LIBJVM}" JAVA_CPPFLAGS="'-I${JAVA_HOME}/include -I${JAVA_HOME}/include/darwin -I$(dirname "${LIBJVM}")'"
# Link Java runtime to R library folder so it can be found.
ln -fs "$LIBJVM" /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Libraries
```

Now you *should* be able to launch R and install rJava ok.

If you're using a Homebrew installation of R instead (needs to be installed with the `--with-java` option), use this line to link the Java runtime instead:

```
ln -fs "$LIBJVM" "$(brew --prefix r)/lib"
```

The process requires admin permissions on macOS (unless R is installed via Homebrew). The R package installer gives admin permission to the various files, so `sudo` isn't needed, luckily. For reference I've also recently written a brief [article](http://www.snaq.net/software/rjava-macos.php) on this issue.

Comment: Any idea why when rJava it unlinks from the original home directory? It seems like when I update any sort of packages which rJava depends on, it unbinds.

Comment: For recent versions of Java/R/rJava this issue should now be resolved, and you shouldn't need to use this fix any more. I'm currently using R 3.5.2 with rJava 0.9-10, and it works without issue for me using Java Development Kit 8/10/11/13.

Answer (score 0):

rJava, R, Java and macOS is a mess.

What you can do is to try rebuild rJava from the sources.

Make sure to reconfigure Java. Due to the fact javareconf makes lots of strong assumptions when it comes to macOS and JAVA (one of these is, that whenever you have "Home" word, in JAVA_HOME variable, it will assume you want to use System wide Java - not quite good idea), you need to:

- create "artificial" Home inside JDK, e.g.

  `cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_11.jdk/Contents
  ln -s Home RHome`
- export RHome as JAVA_HOME

  `export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_11.jdk/Contents/RHome`

Run javareconf with loots of switches that will make gcc with JNI based code compilation

```
`sudo R CMD javareconf JAVA_HOME=${JAVA_HOME} JAVA=${JAVA_HOME/bin/java JAVAC=${JAVA_HOME}/bin/javac JAVAH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin/javah JAR=${JAVA_HOME}/bin/jar JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/server JAVA_CPPFLAGS="-I${JAVA_HOME}/include -I${JAVA_HOME}/include/darwin"`
```

Download rJava package and try to rebuild it manually (outside R)

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rJava/index.html

```
> curl https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/rJava_0.9-8.tar.gz -o rJava_0.9-8.tar.gz
> tar zxf rJava_0.9-8.tar.gz
> cd rJava
> ./configure
```

if it passes, start R (in the same console where you have set env)

```
> install.packages("rJava", type="source")
```

Note that with messy Java installations (Apple's JREs, Oracle's JDKs) you might need to play with setting up Java env propperly in a first place. It might be you will need some "dirty" hacks where you link *javac*, *javah* and *jar* from JDK inside JRE. You will know when you need to do it once `./configure` complains about missing commands.

It also might be needed to update file

```
`/usr/libexec/java_home`/../Info.plist
```

and make sure your JVM can handle JNI. You need to change:

```
<key>JVMCapabilities</key>
<array>
  <string>CommandLine</string>
</array>
```

to

```
<key>JVMCapabilities</key>
<array>
  <string>CommandLine</string>
  <string>JNI</string>
</array>
```

After some struggle, you might get it working fine. However, it's really system dependent. A lot depends on what version of R you have, whether you have JDK installed or not and what is your default JVM.

**Note!**

rJava requires XQuartz for compilation, make sure to install it as well

https://www.xquartz.org